# Looping through multiple rows of dates whilst iterating dates inbetween

Tags: excel, vba, loops, date

I've a dataset showing the input table on the left & the output table on the right.

The first date range iterates as I expect.

I can't get the next rows to iterate their date ranges or the other cells to be populated.

Step 1 is to get the dates to iterate.
[image]

```vb
Sub GenerateDates()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim finalRow, finalRow2, startRow As Long

finalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
finalRow2 = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To 4 'finalRow
    finalRow2 = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    startRow = finalRow2 + 1

    Range("M" & startRow) = Range("A" & i)
    
    j = i
    
    Days = Int((Range("B" & i) - Range("A" & i)))
       
    Do While j < 2 + Days
        j = j + 1
        Range("M" & j) = Range("M" & j - 1) + 1
    Loop
    
    Range("N" & startRow) = Range("C" & i)
    Range("O" & startRow) = ""
    Range("P" & startRow) = Range("F" & i)
    Range("Q" & startRow) = Range("G" & i)
    
Next i

End Sub
```

Target output sample:
[image]

Comment: Consider posting your data as text to make it more useful.  See  [Markdown Tables Generator](http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) for a useful tool.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the conundrum myself.  :-)

```
Sub GenerateDates()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim i, j, numDays As Integer
Dim finalRow, finalRow2 As Long
Dim startDate, endDate As Date
Dim strType, strName, strCountry As String

finalRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
finalRow2 = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

If finalRow2 > 1 Then
    Range("M2:Q" & finalRow2).Select
    Selection.ClearContents
End If

Range("A1").Select

For i = 2 To finalRow
    startDate = Range("A" & i).Value
    endDate = Range("B" & i).Value
    startDate = startDate - 1
    strType = Range("C" & i).Value
    numDays = Range("D" & i).Value
    strName = Range("F" & i).Value
    strCountry = Range("G" & i).Value

    Do While startDate < endDate
        finalRow2 = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        finalRow2 = finalRow2 + 1
        startDate = DateAdd("d", 1, startDate)
        Range("M" & finalRow2).Value = startDate
        Range("N" & finalRow2).Value = strType
        'Function to split decimal numDays
        Range("P" & finalRow2).Value = strName
        Range("Q" & finalRow2).Value = strCountry
    Loop
Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```